# CLLocationManagerDelegate mocking on users denial

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

**-- Final Edit:**
More accurate question [Unit Test CLLocationManager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376000/unit-test-cllocationmanager-implementation)

I'm trying to mock CLLocationManagerDelegate to handle users denial about being geolocated

```
id locationManager = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[CLLocationManager class]];
[[[locationManager stub] andReturnValue:@(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)] authorizationStatus];

id delegateTarget = [OCMockObject niceMockForProtocol:@protocol(CLLocationManagerDelegate)];
[[delegateTarget expect] locationManager:locationManager didFailWithError:[OCMArg any]];

[locationManager setDelegate:delegateTarget];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[delegateTarget verify];
```

However this code doesn't work, I keep getting this error:

> Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>       File: Unknown
>       Line: Unknown
>       Reason: OCMockObject[CLLocationManagerDelegate]: expected method was not invoked: locationManager:OCMockObject[CLLocationManager] didFailWithError:

How can I be sure that the CLLocationManagerDelegate method locationManager:didFailWithError: is getting called?

Edit:
If I use partialMock instead of niceMock for my CLLocationManager instance:

```
CLLocationManager *trueLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
id locationManager = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:trueLocationManager];
[[[locationManager stub] andReturnValue:@(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)] authorizationStatus];

id delegateTarget = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(CLLocationManagerDelegate)];
[[delegateTarget expect] locationManager:trueLocationManager didFailWithError:[OCMArg any]];

[locationManager setDelegate:delegateTarget];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[delegateTarget verify];
```

I get this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'OCMockObject[CLLocationManagerDelegate]: unexpected method invoked: locationManager: didChangeAuthorizationStatus:2 
>       expected:   locationManager: didFailWithError:'

So I thought I got it and added the code below before my delegateTarget expectation of didFailWithError

```
[[delegateTarget expect] locationManager:trueLocationManager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:2]; // kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied = 2
```

And the result is:

> Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>       File: Unknown
>       Line: Unknown
>       Reason: OCMockObject[CLLocationManagerDelegate] : 2 expected methods were not invoked: 
>           locationManager: didChangeAuthorizationStatus:2
>           locationManager: didFailWithError:

Really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Edit2: for Ilea Cristian

```
CLLocationManager *trueLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
id locationManager = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:trueLocationManager];
[[[locationManager stub] andReturnValue:@(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)] authorizationStatus];

id delegateTarget = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(CLLocationManagerDelegate)];
[[delegateTarget expect] locationManager:locationManager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:2]; // kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied = 2
[[delegateTarget expect] locationManager:locationManager didFailWithError:[OCMArg any]];

[locationManager setDelegate:delegateTarget];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[delegateTarget verify];
```

I got this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'OCMockObject[CLLocationManagerDelegate]: unexpected method invoked: locationManager: didChangeAuthorizationStatus:2 
>       expected:   locationManager:OCPartialMockObject[CLLocationManager] didChangeAuthorizationStatus:2
>       expected:   locationManager:OCPartialMockObject[CLLocationManager] didFailWithError:'

Looks like locationManager used in the delegate callback is the trueLocationManager not the locationManager (partialMock)

**-- Final Edit:**
More accurate question [Unit Test CLLocationManager implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376000/unit-test-cllocationmanager-implementation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Test CLLocationManager implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376000/unit-test-cllocationmanager-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You have this line:

```
[locationManager setDelegate:delegateTarget];
```

This means that when `locationManager:didFailWithError:` is called, the object that is passed for the `CLLocationManager` parameter will be your OCMock object named `locationManager` - AND NOT `trueLocationManager`.

Your expectation:

```
[[delegateTarget expect] locationManager:trueLocationManager didFailWithError:[OCMArg any]];
```

So, you are expecting a call that passes the `trueLocationManager`, but instead the partial mock is passed. Try expecting the partial mock to be passed.

OCMock partial mocks, like `locationManager`, are just proxy wrappers over the real object, but their type is different (that's why you used `id` instead of real types).

This magic works because of the way Objective-C handles calls through message passing. If you read a bit about the [NSProxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then you look at the [OCMock implementation](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock) you will truly understand how some backstage stuff works.

EDIT:

Personally I don't know what do you really want to test. The Apple framework? None of the entities there are your classes/protocols. What are you testing?

I guess you have a ViewController that implements the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol. Mock that class. If your location manager is a property, stub it to return your fake location manager (so that internally the vc uses the fake). Or set the fake locationManager.delegate to be your ViewController. Start the fake location manager.

Expect the ViewControllers delegate methods to be called. If your location manager is a singleton, then [it's a bit tricky to replace it](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/02/mocking-singletons-with-ocmock/) with a fake/stub.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was my first attempt in my edit but I had to change it because it didn't worked. See my question edit.

Comment: What happens if you expect [OCMArg any] instead of `trueLocationManager` or `locationManager` ?

Comment: Replacing by [OCMArg any] doesn't solve the problem.
Initially what I wanted was to test my class that handles CLLocationManager. I wanted to test what methods were being called when users deny geolocation. Maybe I should re-open another question and delete this one that is not accurate enough.

Comment: Maybe this is a more accurate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376000/unit-test-cllocationmanager-implementation

Answer (score 0):

You have created a "nice mock" for your LocationManager. This means that your calls to `setDelegate:` and `startUpdatingLocation` will be silently ignored. You *could* switch this to a partial mock, but are you just testing the LocationManager? You should only need to test your implementation of the location manager delegate -- you can just call those delegate methods directly.

Comment: In fact initially I was trying to test my encapsulation of the CLLocationManager and CLLocationManagerDelegate responses but couldn't find a working solution either so I went back to direct test of CLLocationManager in my test case (hence my question).

About your answer, I edited my initial question with several code asumptions. Thanks for your time.