# Unit Test CLLocationManager implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, cllocationmanager, ocmock

I have a class named "`GeolocationManager`" that handles a `CLLocationManager` object and `delegate` responses.

```
- (void)getGeolocationForClient:(id<GeolocationManagerDelegate>)client
{
    _delegate = client;
    _locationManager = [self createLocationManager];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   // do some stuff
}
```

createLocationManager is a public method ready to be stubbed

```
- (CLLocationManager *)createLocationManager
{
    return [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}
```

What I want to achieve is to test that when user denies being geolocated the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `locationManager:didFailWithError:` is being called on my `GeolocationManager` object.

My test method below does not seem to be working

```
- (void)testOnUserDenial
{
    GeolocationManager *geolocationManager = [[GeolocationManager alloc] init];
    id geolocationManagerTest = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:geolocationManager];

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    id locationManagerTest = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:locationManager];

    [[[locationManagerTest stub] andReturnValue:@(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)] authorizationStatus];
    [[[geolocationManagerTest stub] andReturn:locationManagerTest] createLocationManager];

    [[geolocationManagerTest expect] locationManager:[OCMArg any] didFailWithError:[OCMArg any]];

    [geolocationManagerTest getGeolocationForClient:[OCMArg any]];

    [geolocationManagerTest verify];
}
```

> Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException    File: Unknown   Line: Unknown
>     Reason: OCPartialMockObject[GeolocationManager]: expected method was
>   not invoked: locationManager:OCPartialMockObject[CLLocationManager]
>   didFailWithError:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `OCMOCK_VALUE(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)` for the returnValue?

Comment: [[[locationManagerTest stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)] authorizationStatus];
Cannot build, I got : "semantic issue - address expression must be an Ivalue or a function designator".

Comment: Does your OCMocks version of `OCMOCK_VALUE` is the same as https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/master/Source/OCMock/OCMArg.h ?

Comment: My version differs. My version is 2.2.1 from http://ocmock.org/download/
With the OCMArg.h version you provided I can build but still got the same error : expected method was not invoked: locationManager:<OCMAnyConstraint: 0x7499840> didFailWithError:<OCMAnyConstraint: 0x7499870>